# Export charts from Excel as Images in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel

I'm trying to export Excel worksheets as png, from a specific range, which I'm grabbing using openpyxl, but I can't get it to work. I've tried using excel2img 1.4.0 but it doesn't work for Excel 2016, only Excel <= 2013.

The line i run for testing, without the range parameters, to get a full page:

```
excel2img.export_img("myfile.xlsx", "outfile.png", "Planilha2", None)
```

The error i get when trying to run excel2img

> <win32com.gen_py.Microsoft Excel 16.0 Object Library.Range instance at
> 0x1928524655440>' object has no attribute 'parent'

I've seen some people use C#, but I can't code in C yet.

Is there any other way of turning spreadsheets to png?

Thanks!

Comment: Which versions are you using? What does the relevant calling code look like? What specifically happens when you say it doesn't work?

Comment: Added some more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well, i kinda figured it out.

First i converted the worksheet to html, then converted that to JPG.

```
Code:
from xlsx2html import xlsx2html
import imgkit

html = xlsx2html("myfile.xlsx", "outfile.html")
imgkit.from_file('outfile.html', 'result.jpg')
```

Rather simple really. Not perfect but it'll do